# In Linux How to check through scripts what version of Java is installed?

Tags: java, linux, bash

alternate --config is updated

java -version works

How do i verify if java is installed if java is installed and what version. What is the correct way.

Comment: if java -version works what is your question?

Comment: are you also trying to find Java if it is not already on a search path?

Comment: through scripts. Should i search through output of java -version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -x /usr/bin/java ] ; then
        java -version 2>&1 | head -1 | awk -F '"' '{print $2}'
else
        exit
fi
```

**OUTPUT** (on my linux box):

```
1.6.0_18
```

check whether the java executable is present. if yes, then print the version.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following code may help you, please try it,

```
a=`(java -version) 2>&1`
if [[ "$a" == *1.7* ]]
then 
    echo '1.7'
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you expect it to be installed; there are two ways to find the `java` binary:

- look for `java` in PATH (which is what you're doing by executing `java -version`)
- if `JAVA_HOME` is defined, treat that as the preferred installation and run `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version`

After that, just extract the version number from the output as you need (see slayedbylucifer's answer above).